# Issue while turning apply in R

Tags: r, apply

Can someone help understand how this works? thanks
[image]

Comment: ``?apply`` and ``?cumprod`` are your friends.

Comment: It computes the cumulative products by rows. Then returns those products as column vectors, since R is column-major. To have the same shape, transpose the output with `t()`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Rui's comment, you have the following matrix:

```r
pRx <- matrix(c(0.943789, 0.996136, 0.958197, 0.916871, 0.904984,
                0.905841, 0.957261, 0.959938, 0.946062, 0.968895,
                0.901151, 0.992503, 0.997188, 0.907040, 0.930833),
              ncol =  3L)
pRx
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.943789 0.905841 0.901151
[2,] 0.996136 0.957261 0.992503
[3,] 0.958197 0.959938 0.997188
[4,] 0.916871 0.946062 0.907040
[5,] 0.904984 0.968895 0.930833
```

Now consider the call

```r
apply(pRx, 1, cumprod)
```

`apply` is a function which **applies** a passed functional argument to a matrix or an array. The function you are passing is `cumprod` which takes as input a *vector* and returns another vector of the same length whose elements are the **cum**ulative **prod**uct of the elements of the first vector. Lastly, by passing `1` to the `MARGIN` element of `apply`, you are asking that `cumprod` be applied to the matrix in a **row-wise** fashion.

So what should the answer be? It should be a data structure with 5 elements, each of length three, comprising the first column, the first column times the second column, and lastly the product of all three columns.

What Rui points out, and which can be seen in the `byrow` element of `?matrix`, is that R by default fills its matrices in column-order. Which means that the the `cumprod` of row 1 of `pRx` becomes the first column of the output. The `cumprod` of row 2 of `pRx` becomes the second column of the output. And so on, which is exactly what is returned. For example:

```r
apply(pRx, 1, cumprod)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.9437890 0.9961360 0.9581970 0.9168710 0.9049840
[2,] 0.8549228 0.9535621 0.9198097 0.8674168 0.8768345
[3,] 0.7704145 0.9464133 0.9172232 0.7867817 0.8161865
```

Now manually:

```r
for (i in 1:5) print(cumprod(pRx[i, ]))
[1] 0.9437890 0.8549228 0.7704145
[1] 0.9961360 0.9535621 0.9464133
[1] 0.9581970 0.9198097 0.9172232
[1] 0.9168710 0.8674168 0.7867817
[1] 0.9049840 0.8768345 0.8161865
```

If you want the output of the `apply` to be rowwise instead of columnwise, then simply ***t**ranspose* the output:

```r
t(apply(pRx, 1, cumprod))
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.943789 0.8549228 0.7704145
[2,] 0.996136 0.9535621 0.9464133
[3,] 0.958197 0.9198097 0.9172232
[4,] 0.916871 0.8674168 0.7867817
[5,] 0.904984 0.8768345 0.8161865
```